# Set different Session variables for sites on one domain

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have several websites in one domain (virtual host):
`website.com/site1`, `website.com/site2` etc. 
On each site there is a authentification, which saves the `username` in `Session`.

The problem is:
If I'm on `site1`, and, let's say, Alex accecced to `site2` from my browser, site1 would think that I'm Alex. And if I do something, Alex will be written in the DB.

One solution, is to check whether the `Session` and the `username` is the same on each action.

Is there a solution to set different `$_SESSION['name']` for `site1` and `site2`, using the same `$_SESSION['name']` variable?

Comment: Could you use `$_SESSION['site1']['name']` and `$_SESSION['site2']['name']`?

Comment: I want to use one variable. Actually, I don't want to change all variables in all sites now. There are a lot of other Session variables :)

Comment: Check this out, (Same domain, different folder PHP session): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479626/same-domain-different-folder-php-session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same domain, different folder PHP session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479626/same-domain-different-folder-php-session)

Comment: It's not different folders. Just different php files. However, thanks, I'll check.

Comment: Yes! It would work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have a lazy solution if it could work for you that.

In

### website.com/site1

When you start a session that means you do some functionalities and then store it in database like

```
//SQL things and finally
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

you can do this

```
 $_SESSION['site1-username'] = $username;
```

Similarly in other site

```
$_SESSION['site2-username'] = $username;
```

Comment: I don't want to change all php files now)

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is found:

JS each 5 seconds sends to he server the username. Server checks if it's equal to Session. If not, the user is asked for authentification.