# Ci using same session at different project

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have 2 web aplication using CI. the problem is every project sharing same session. i need every project to use different session.

Comment: On the same domain?

Comment: yes same domain. but different folder. like localhost/web1 and localhost/web2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same domain, different folder PHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479626/same-domain-different-folder-php-session) (note that the accepted answer comes with a caveat in the comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the [`sess_cookie_name`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences) value in your configs (by default this is in `application/config/config.php`).

Depending on your setup, you could be using the same store (`database` / `redis`) or with the `files` store the same `sess_save_path` in both projects. If you separate the project by session cookie's name they should not collide anymore.

Alternatively you could change the `sess_save_path` to an unique one for every project if you are using the `files` driver