# Avoid sharing PHP session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a rare situation with PHP sessions.
I have a web server running Apache2 (Linux Debian 10).

I developed a mini CRM using PHP and MySQL.
My miniCRM is hosted in the same server but in two different directories, example: **192.168.0.233/app/1/login.php** and **192.168.0.233/app/2/login.php**.

I noticed that if I do login via **192.168.0.233/app/1** the session is also shown on **192.168.0.233/app/2**.

I would like somebody help me to avoid this. I don't want the session created on **app/1** be able in **app/2**. I would like to keep them separated.

In the mini CRM, the script **login.php** starts the session with these code:

```
    @$_SESSION["logged_user"] = "$post_username";
```

**Note:** The linux debian is running in VirtualBox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same domain, different folder PHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479626/same-domain-different-folder-php-session)

Comment: Why you don't make different session variables

Answer (score 0):

Right now at 3:44 AM I have found the solution.

This is what I did.

Inside **app/1** I created a folder called **tmp** with **777** permissions

`$ cd app/1`

`$mkdir tmp`

`$ chmod -R 777 tmp`

Inside **app/2** I created a folder called **tmp** with **777** permissions

`$ cd app/2`

`$mkdir tmp`

`$ chmod -R 777 tmp`

Inside **app/1** I have created a **.htaccess** with this line:

`php_value session.save_path "/var/www/html/app/1/tmp"`

Inside **app/2** I have created a **.htaccess** with this line:

`php_value session.save_path "/var/www/html/app/2/tmp"`

Done!

Now the session name is the same "logged_user" but they do not mix-up.

How each **app/1** and **app/2** are running the same mini CRM but each **app/1** and **app/2** save the PHP session inside their own **tmp** folder.

Take care, I am going to bed now :D