# How to make a html login form so that chrome understands that it is not same username/password as my other login form on same domain

Tags: html, authentication

I have a site with some off the shelf services like phpmyadmin et cetera.

Now I have added my own login page for a different service on the same domain, but chrome always mix up the different services. If I add a user and password for one of the services then chrome thinks it will work for all login pages on the same domain,

Now is there any way to tell chrome that each login page on this site are for different services and have unique users and passwords?

The only way I have found so far is to use different usernames on the different sub pages of the domain, but I think there should be a better way.

It feels like this questions should have been asked before, but I have not been able to find it when searching this forum and the web. Getting loads of hits, but it is always about something else.

Comment: Chrome controls this by domain, I don't know of any way to override that behavior.  You could use cookies on your website and disable the auto-signin feature of the browser.

Comment: What language are you using for your current login form? PHP? Well, PHP shares session data for the entire domain I think. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479626/same-domain-different-folder-php-session

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP but I'm not using the PHP built in session handling, instead I use my own. Anyway if there's no way to make chrome understand that there are different user databases behind the different web pages, then I guess I need to fall back on using different names for the different web-pages on my domain.